# Reformarring complex factor vector with comma separation after thousand

Tags: r, string, vector, character, gsub

I would like to reformat a factor vector so the figures that it contains have a thousand separator. The vector contains integer and real number without any particular rule with respect to the values or order.

## Data

In particular, I'm working with a vector `vec` similar to the one generated below:

```
content <- c("0 - 100", "0 - 100", "0 - 100", "0 - 100",
             "150.22 - 170.33",
             "1000 - 2000","1000 - 2000", "1000 - 2000", "1000 - 2000", 
             "7000 - 10000", "7000 - 10000", "7000 - 10000", "7000 - 10000",
             "7000 - 10000", "1000000 - 22000000", "1000000 - 22000000", 
             "1000000 - 22000000",
             "44000000 - 66000000.8989898989")

vec <- factor(x = content, levels = unique(content))
```

## Desired results

My ambition is to reformat this vector so the figures contain the *Excel-like* **1,000** separataor, as in the example below:

> 100.00 
>   1,000.00
>   1,000,000.00
>   1,000,000.56
>   24,564,000,000.56

---

## Tried approach

I was thinking of making use of the `gsubfn` and a proto object that would pass the digit. Then maybe createing another proto object with 3 digits and replacing. As suggested in the code below:

```
gsubfn(pattern = "[0-9][0-9][0-9]", replacement = ~paste0(x, ','), 
       x = as.character(vec))
```

This works only partuially as comma is insterted in:

> "150,.22 - 170,.33"

which obviously is wrong. I also had to convert the character vector to factor. Consquently, my question boils down to two elements:

- How can I work around the comma issue?
- **How can I maintain the original structure of the factor?** - *I need to have a factor vector ordered in the same manner as the original one but with commas in right places.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operating *only* on the `levels` seem to keep your precision level, not converting your vector to `character` vector and much more efficient as it is reducing the size of the data you operate on only to the unique values (rather the whole vector)

```
levels(vec) <- sapply(strsplit(levels(vec), " - "), 
                       function(x) paste(prettyNum(x, 
                                            big.mark = ",", 
                                            preserve.width = "none"), 
                                   collapse = " - "))
vec
#  [1] 0 - 100                            0 - 100                            0 - 100                            0 - 100                            150.22 - 170.33                   
#  [6] 1,000 - 2,000                      1,000 - 2,000                      1,000 - 2,000                      1,000 - 2,000                      7,000 - 10,000                    
# [11] 7,000 - 10,000                     7,000 - 10,000                     7,000 - 10,000                     7,000 - 10,000                     1,000,000 - 22,000,000            
# [16] 1,000,000 - 22,000,000             1,000,000 - 22,000,000             44,000,000 - 66,000,000.8989898989
# Levels: 0 - 100 150.22 - 170.33 1,000 - 2,000 7,000 - 10,000 1,000,000 - 22,000,000 44,000,000 - 66,000,000.8989898989
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your contribution. So the complete solution would be to address the `levels` and content of the factor separatly?

Comment: The `levels` are integral part of the content. If you address them, you address the content, the only difference is that you are not converting your vector to `character` and then back to `factor` (which could cost lots of memory for a big vector) and you also operating only on the unique values. Though I haven't really tested for efficiency the whole process and rather mainly speculating.

Answer (score 1):

Use positive lookahead based regex...

```
content <- c("0 - 100", "0 - 100", "0 - 100", "0 - 100",
              "1000 - 2000","1000 - 2000", "1000 - 2000", "1000 - 2000", 
              "7000 - 10000", "7000 - 10000", "7000 - 10000", "7000 - 10000",
              "7000 - 10000", "1000000 - 22000000", "1000000 - 22000000", 
              "1000000 - 22000000")
gsub("(\\d)(?=(?:\\d{3})+\\b)", "\\1,", content, perl=T)
# [1] "0 - 100"                "0 - 100"                "0 - 100"               
# [4] "0 - 100"                "1,000 - 2,000"          "1,000 - 2,000"         
# [7] "1,000 - 2,000"          "1,000 - 2,000"          "7,000 - 10,000"        
# [10] "7,000 - 10,000"         "7,000 - 10,000"         "7,000 - 10,000"        
# [13] "7,000 - 10,000"         "1,000,000 - 22,000,000" "1,000,000 - 22,000,000"
# [16] "1,000,000 - 22,000,000"
```

Comment: I recon that I have to learn more about lookaheads. BTW, I may have really messy values, like `"44000000 - 66000000.8989898989"`. Ideally, I want to mimick what this unfortunate *thousand separator* in Excel does. Also, I have this addittional hassle of sorting the levels in this thing.

Comment: `gsub("(\\d)(?=(?:\\d{3})+[\\s.])", "\\1,", content, perl=T)`

Comment: Works in terms of fixing the unfortunate number. Presumeably, I can make use of [the somehow related discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522278/ordering-a-complex-string-vector-in-order-to-obtain-a-ordered-factor) to order it again and make a nice factor.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `formatC` :

```
sapply(
  X = lapply(
    X = strsplit(x = content, split = " - "),
    FUN = function(x) {
      formatC(x = as.numeric(x), format = "f", flag = "#", big.mark = ",", 
              decimal.mark = ".", digits = 2, drop0trailing = FALSE)
    }
  ),
  FUN = paste, collapse = " - "
)
# [1] "0.00 - 100.00"                 "0.00 - 100.00"                 "0.00 - 100.00"                
# [4] "0.00 - 100.00"                 "150.22 - 170.33"               "1,000.00 - 2,000.00"          
# [7] "1,000.00 - 2,000.00"           "1,000.00 - 2,000.00"           "1,000.00 - 2,000.00"          
# [10] "7,000.00 - 10,000.00"          "7,000.00 - 10,000.00"          "7,000.00 - 10,000.00"         
# [13] "7,000.00 - 10,000.00"          "7,000.00 - 10,000.00"          "1,000,000.00 - 22,000,000.00" 
# [16] "1,000,000.00 - 22,000,000.00"  "1,000,000.00 - 22,000,000.00"  "44,000,000.00 - 66,000,000.90"
```

Comment: It works to an extent, it rounded the last value `"44,000,000.00 - 66,000,000.90"` but I can live with this. The thing is that I've to get ordered factor not a character vector at the end of the transformation. Simply put, I want my original variables with *Excel-like* thousand separators in the right places.