# big mark number in cut R

Tags: r

I want to keep a order after change big mark in numbers cut. The reproducible examples:

```
require(dplyr)
data <- c(rnorm(25, 2000, 500), 19, 10)
data <- data %>% cut(., breaks = 5, dig.lab = 4)
levels(data)
```

Results:

```
"(7.265,557]" "(557,1104]"  "(1104,1651]" "(1651,2198]" "(2198,2748]"
```

When I change the format:

```
nd_data <- data %>% prettyNum(big.mark = ".")  %>% as.factor()
levels(nd_data)
"(1.104,1.651]" "(1.651,2.198]" "(2.198,2.748]" "  (557,1.104]" "  (7.265,557]"
```

The order change. How to keep, without a manual change, because I have different data sets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reformarring complex factor vector with comma separation after thousnad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608324/reformarring-complex-factor-vector-with-comma-separation-after-thousnad)

Comment: Didn't you read the warning message????

Answer (score 1):

Use `factor` and specify `levels` explicitly from `data`

```
library(dplyr)

nd_data <- data %>% 
              prettyNum(big.mark = ".") %>% 
              factor(., levels = prettyNum(levels(data), big.mark = "."))

levels(data)
#[1] "(6.802,649.6]" "(649.6,1289]"  "(1289,1929]"   "(1929,2568]"   "(2568,3211]"  

levels(nd_data)
#[1] "(6.802,649.6]" " (649.6,1289]" "(1.289,1.929]" "(1.929,2.568]" "(2.568,3.211]"
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
data <- c(rnorm(25, 2000, 500), 19, 10)
data <- data %>% cut(., breaks = 5, dig.lab = 4)
```